# VBA IF-Condition within an HTML-Body of an E-Mail

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet:

```
    A       B
1   10
2   20
```

And I use the following VBA to send out an E-Mail:

```
Sub Test_EMail4()
    If ExitAll = False Then
        Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
        Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OMail
            .Display
            End With
            signature = OMail.HTMLbody
            With OMail
            .To = "test@test.de"
            .Subject = "test"
            .HTMLbody = "<p> Permant Content goes here </p>"
            If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 10 Then
            .HTMLbody = "<p> Content if Formula is true </p>"
            Else
            End If
            End With
        Set OMail = Nothing
        Set OApp = Nothing
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see I have an If-condition within the HTML-Body.
I want to achieve that the first tag `<p> Permanet content goes here </p>` is always shown in the E-Mail whereas the secont tag `<p> Content if Formula is true </p>` is only displayed if the condition in the IF-Formula is met *(as in this case)*.

Right now, it only shows the content within the IF-Formula in the E-Mail. How can I also include the permanent part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build the message outside of the `With OMail` block like this:

```
Dim strBody As String

strBody = "<p> Permant Content goes here </p>"
If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 10 Then
    strBody = strBody & "<p> Content if Formula is true </p>"
End If
```

Then set `strBody` to the `HTMLbody` per your current code:

```
Sub Test_EMail4()

    Dim strBody As String
    Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String

    strBody = "<p> Permant Content goes here </p>"
    If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 10 Then
        strBody = strBody & "<p> Content if Formula is true </p>"
    End If

    If ExitAll = False Then
        Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OMail
            .display
        End With
        signature = OMail.HTMLBody
        With OMail
            .To = "test@test.de"
            .Subject = "test"
            .HTMLBody = strBody
        End With
        Set OMail = Nothing
        Set OApp = Nothing
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Robin, do I have to consider something when I copy the two codes in my VBA? When I type them in the VBA there is no content shown in my E-Mail.

Comment: See my edit - hope that helps - included suggestion with your original code in entire `Sub`

Comment: Hi Robin, when I put your code I get the error "Object required (424)". I tried to put a Sub () ... End Sub () around the first code but it still does not work. Do you know where my mistake is?

Comment: Hi Michi - the first code block is just an example. Intention is just for you to paste in the second block from `Sub Test_EMail4()` through to `End Sub`. I included the code to set the email body in the `Test_Email4()` sub. What line do you get the error on?

Comment: Hi Robin, I did a mistake because I have to replace the Sheet1 in my Excel-spreasheet with another number. Now it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Robin, the only thing I just saw is that right now my signature is not shown in the E-Mail anymore. How do I have to change the code to include my signature?

Comment: Change `.HTMLBody = strBody` to `.HTMLBody = strBody & vbCrLf & signature`

Answer (score 0):

from what you put this solves it. Removed the `Signature`since there is no need for that imo.

```
Sub Test_EMail4()
If ExitAll = False Then
    Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object
    Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OMail
        .Display
        .To = "test@test.de"
        .Subject = "test"
        If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 10 Then
        .HTMLBody = "<p> Permant Content goes here </p>" & .HTMLBody
        Else
        .HTMLBody = "<p> Content if Formula is true </p>" & .HTMLBody
        End If
        End With
        With OMail
        .Display 'change to "send" 
        End With

    Set OMail = Nothing
    Set OApp = Nothing
Else
End If
End Sub
```